C# Linq. Join collections by ID
I've got three collections with common key:
var shops = new[] { new { shopId = "1", shopName = "shop1" }, new { shopId = "2", shopName = "shop2" } , new { shopId = "3", shopName = "shop3" }};
var sales = new[] { new { shopId = "1", sales = "1000", place = 2 }, new { shopId = "2", sales = "0", place = 1 } , new { shopId = "3", sales = "100", place = 3 }};
var unpostedChecks = new[] { new { shopId = "1", checkQnt = 2 }};

How can I join these collections, using c# LINQ, to get result like that?:
var result = new[] { 
    new { shopId = "1", shopName = "shop1", sales = "1000", place = 2, checkQnt = 2 }, 
    new { shopId = "2", shopName = "shop2", place = 1 , sales = 0, checkQnt = 0},
    new { shopId = "3", shopName = "shop3", sales = "100", place = 3 , checkQnt = 0}
};


You'd need to use Select and make a new type with all the properties you want projected, either a concrete type or an anonymous type. Can you clarify what your problem is? Are you unsure how to lookup each record that has the same shop Id, or how to combine all the data for the same shop id?

Could you edit your code block to be valid C#? This looks more like JSON/JavaScript.

I made the code legal, but I had to add "sales = 0" in two places so the object types will match up. If this breaks the OP's scenario, they should edit to correct it.

@gunr2171 The problem is that collections have different quantity of records, and JOIN method in this example return one-record-collection as a result.

@JoelCoehoorn ok, thnx, how can I pre-fill "0" values in last collection (unpostedChecks) to match up. Is it possible to do "on-the-fly" while using linq methods. I got this collections from Odata service.

If you have three sets, you start with one, and then adding each additional set is an additional Join. SQL is the same way.
Assuming my edit to the question is faithful to the problem, that will look something like this:
var result = shops.
    Join(sales, shop => shop.shopId, sales => sales.shopId,
                 (shop, sales) => new { shopId = shop.shopId, shop = shop, sales = sales } ).
    Join(unpostedChecks, ss => ss.shopId, upc => upc.shopId,
                 (ss, upc) => new {shopId = ss.shopId, shopName = ss.shop.shopName, sales = ss.sales.sales, place = ss.sales.place, checkQnt = upc.checkQnt } );

Note for the intermediate join I only pulled out the shopId to its own property, to make it easy to use as a key for the next step. For the other properties I just packaged the entire objects in the intermediate state, rather than rebuilding individual elements. This is also more efficient, since the intermediate objects only need the object reference to the original item, instead of copying the data.
The problem here is this is still an INNER JOIN, and it seems you want an SQL -style LEFT OUTER JOIN. This can be done in C# using GroupJoin() plus the DefaultIfEmpty() method on the result, but I'm out of time today to take that next step.

I'll try this, thank you
